# the random port initiates the TCP request

Tags: linux, tcp, centos, superuser, time-wait

the random port initiates the TCP request between two server programs on centos 6.8.

```
# netstat -an|grep 6001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52470             127.0.0.1:6001              TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52599             127.0.0.1:6001              TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52428             127.0.0.1:6001              TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52640             127.0.0.1:6001              TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50038             127.0.0.1:6001              ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6001              127.0.0.1:50038             ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52510             127.0.0.1:6001              TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52559             127.0.0.1:6001              TIME_WAIT
```

Some TIME_WAITs always exist, I don't understand why.

```
# tcpdump -ni lo port 6001
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
08:55:01.001341 IP 127.0.0.1.50038 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [P.], seq 12:24, ack 1, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 9066110 ecr 9056110], length 12
08:55:01.001358 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.50038: Flags [.], ack 24, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9066110 ecr 9066110], length 0
08:55:02.947977 IP 127.0.0.1.50038 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [P.], seq 24:42, ack 1, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 9068056 ecr 9066110], length 18
08:55:02.947987 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.50038: Flags [.], ack 42, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9068056 ecr 9068056], length 0
08:55:08.107233 IP 127.0.0.1.53349 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [S], seq 4256285474, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 9073216 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:55:08.107255 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.53349: Flags [S.], seq 3307774380, ack 4256285475, win 65483, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 9073216 ecr 9073216,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:55:08.107271 IP 127.0.0.1.53349 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9073216 ecr 9073216], length 0
08:55:08.107294 IP 127.0.0.1.53349 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9073216 ecr 9073216], length 0
08:55:08.107370 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.53349: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9073216 ecr 9073216], length 0
08:55:08.108237 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.53349: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9073217 ecr 9073216], length 0
08:55:08.108248 IP 127.0.0.1.53349 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9073217 ecr 9073217], length 0
08:55:12.001197 IP 127.0.0.1.50038 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [P.], seq 42:54, ack 1, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 9077109 ecr 9068056], length 12
08:55:12.001206 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.50038: Flags [.], ack 54, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9077110 ecr 9077109], length 0
08:55:16.859786 IP 127.0.0.1.53391 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [S], seq 127196351, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 9081968 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:55:16.859797 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.53391: Flags [S.], seq 1018026274, ack 127196352, win 65483, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 9081968 ecr 9081968,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:55:16.859809 IP 127.0.0.1.53391 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9081968 ecr 9081968], length 0
08:55:16.859827 IP 127.0.0.1.53391 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9081968 ecr 9081968], length 0
08:55:16.860234 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.53391: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9081969 ecr 9081968], length 0
08:55:16.860254 IP 127.0.0.1.53391 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9081969 ecr 9081969], length 0
08:55:22.001768 IP 127.0.0.1.50038 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [P.], seq 54:66, ack 1, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 9087110 ecr 9077110], length 12
08:55:22.001777 IP 127.0.0.1.6001 > 127.0.0.1.50038: Flags [.], ack 66, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 9087110 ecr 9087110], length 0
```

Port 53349 and 53391, Where does the TCP request start? please help.

Comment: On another machine is normal, In short some of the normal but some have the above problems

Comment: Connection is not closed properly. Impossible to say anything else without code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks so much, Not the port is not properly shut down. New TCP request launch from random port.

Comment: Yes, the source port is random, as it should be.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I change 6001 to 30001, there is no such problem，run normal. thanks all~

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: There is no such problem as what? What's the question? I've answered everything I could identify as a question but it appears you're really asking something else entirely.

Comment: The system environment caused unknown tcp request. maybe another service check this port.

Comment: You have two TCP connections, one from each of those ports, over which no data was sent. Both originated locally and both were closed correctly.

Comment: transmit data by ESTABLISHED tcp connections. an unknow service try to access port 6001, i cannt locate it. so i change 6001 to another port.

Comment: @borey I repeat. No data was transmitted from those ports. Check the packet sizes in the dump. They are all `length 0`.

Comment: i know, tcpdump show length = 0. i want to locate that who launch tcp request.

Comment: First time you have actually stated that. You can see that via `netstat`. Just look for the process that has 53349 or 53391 as its local TCP port.

Comment: netstat useless, can not locate.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0):

> the random port initiates the TCP request between two server programs

Correct. The client end port is allocated randomly.

> Some TIME_WAITs always exist, I don't understand why.

Because they always do, at the end which does the first close. It's a defined part of TCP. See [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793).

> Port 53349 and 53391, Where does the TCP request start?

At the end which is using those ports locally. If you're asking which line:

```
8:55:08.107233 IP 127.0.0.1.53349 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [S], seq 4256285474, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 9073216 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

and

```
08:55:16.859786 IP 127.0.0.1.53391 > 127.0.0.1.6001: Flags [S], seq 127196351, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 9081968 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

(S for SYN).